# Get code inside script tag

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm scraping a site with nodejs and cheerio. How can I get the value of `Test`.

Here's the code that I'm scraping.

```
<body>
   <div>Hello</div>
<script>
var Test = "www.example.com";
</script>
</body>
```

How can I get the value of the variable `Test`?

Answer (score 1):

You'd first need to obtain the raw content of the script tag (which you can do with cheerio), once you have the javascript inside the tag, you have options:

- **Safe, but tightly coupled** to the code structure: use regex to find the literal value:

```js
var value = /\sTest\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/.exec(js)[1]
```

- **Safe and flexible**, but more complicated (and performance costly). If the code is too complex to use a regex, and alternative approach is to obtain the AST of that js code, and then you'd just traverse the AST to find the literal you're looking for, you can try Esprima online here to understand what the AST is and how it'd look like: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

For the example you shared, the AST looks like this:

```js
var ast = {
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "VariableDeclaration",
            "declarations": [
                {
                    "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                    "id": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "Test"
                    },
                    "init": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": "www.example.com",
                        "raw": "\"www.example.com\""
                    }
                }
            ],
            "kind": "var"
        }
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}

// you can use something smarter to look for "Test" variable declaration here
var value = ast.body[0].declarations[0].init.value;
```

- **Unsafe**, nasty (see "eval is evil"), but fast and flexible:

```js
// assumes js code is declaring a variable named "Test"
var value = eval(js + '; Test;');

// a slightly better approach that prevents adding variables to the global scope:
var value = eval('(function(){ ' + js + '; return Test; })();')
```

**Big Warning**, never use this eval approach if you don't have complete trust over the content of that script tag, you'd be running that as part of your node.js app, creating a form of Script Injection vulnerability.

Comment: thanks ,sorry but i have to find the Test value every minutes , i know how set interval ,  but i don't know how to find Test value after "="

Comment: what I described are options to do exactly that, find the value after "=", the 1st is maybe the simplest you can try, ie. using a regular expression.
it doesn't matter if you have to do it all repeatedly.